# Registering Actions for ControllerModel in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to add a new `ActionModel` for a `ControllerModel` in an implementation of `IControllerModelConvention`, but I cannot find any documentation or examples of how this model system works or how to do this correctly. I am able to add a new ActionModel easily enough, but it is not routable once the application is running:

```
var action = new ActionModel(method, new object[] { new HttpGetAttribute("/test") })
{
    Controller = controller,
    ActionName = "test"
};
controller.Actions.Add(action);
```

It seems I need to add a selector to the action, perhaps other properties as well, but I haven't been able to find one that exposes this action. Also unsure if my attributes are correct/redundant. Ultimately I would like to add multiple actions that do not map 1:1 to the methods in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

I've made it work similiar to your approach. Maybe this can help you:

**Controller**

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return Ok(new string[] { "Hello", "World" });
    }
}
```

**Model Convention**

```
public class TestControllerModelConvention : IControllerModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(ControllerModel controller)
    {
        Type controllerType = typeof(TestController);
        MethodInfo indexAction = controllerType.GetMethod("Index");

        var testAction = new ActionModel(indexAction, new[] { new HttpGetAttribute("/test") })
        {
            ActionName = "Index",
            Controller = controller
        };
        controller.Actions.Add(testAction);
    }
}
```

**Startup**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // other initialitation stuff

    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.Add(new TestControllerModelConvention());
    }).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
}
```

Now when I start the application and browse "/test" it will hit the controller action.

Comment: This did not work for me in cases where the action method was not a valid action of the controller (i.e. method was private or generic), in these cases I had to add a selector as well. I guess you are benefiting from some mechanism in the default application adding appropriate selectors *if* the method was a valid action. I had assumed that with a convention which included them as actions, the routing portion would "take our word for it" and assign routes from attributes, but that does not seem to be the case.

Comment: How do you add selectors? And to what? `ActionModel.Selectors` is read only.